# Regex string is not ending with

Tags: regex, expression, match

I have a problem, because there are some strings and my expression ist not working...

For expample

String:

```
1. username
2. username- 
3. username-user2
```

Expressions:

```
\w*username\b
```

Now my expression says me both are okay. But i only want to have the one with out this "-" character. The Username shoult be the last word without anything behind in the string.

But when i am searching for "username-user2" the expression should accept the string. But not when i am searching only for "username".

Can anyone help me i am despairing

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Eh `\w*username$` - username + *end of string*?

Comment: What can come after username?

Comment: The Username is the end of the string. Means when i check "username" the expression should not match "username-" or "username-user2"

Comment: thanks your expression \w*username$ works perfectly. You saved my day..

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you don't mind what text appears after username:

```
username(?:-\w+)?$
```

If that isn't the end of the string you can use this:

```
username(?:-\w+)?[^\w]
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression is: `\w*username$`

Comment: Note that `\w*` is useless here